# npm install installing dependencies within dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an issue with the node package manager, I have a `package.json` which looks like following:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.0.1",
    "pusher-js": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

My issue is when I use `npm install` in the root directory of my project it installs all the packages, but instead of installing all modules required by the modules listed in the `package.json`, they are installed separately inside each dependency's folder. Here is how it looks:

```
/root/node_modules
+-- pusher-js
¦   +-- node_modules
¦       +-- faye-websocket
¦       +-- xmlhttprequest
```

Here is how I want it to look:

```
/root/node_modules
+-- pusher-js
+-- faye-websocket
+-- xmlhttprequest
```

I have manager to achieve the latter once, but it was the first time I ever used `npm` and I have no idea of how I did it / it happened.

EDIT 1:

- Here are two links that give some information of what I have been using

  - [Laravel broadcasting # laravel echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts)
  - [Laravel elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir)

EDIT 2: I am using `gulp` to compile my javascript and css assets and when the sub-dependencies are located inside of each dependency folder the compiler does not detect them and throws a not found error. Also it quadruples the amount of files in the `/root/node_modules` folder

Comment: What does `npm -v` show? I believe npm didn't start flattening out the dependency structure until v3.x.

Comment: If your code depends on a module, you need to declare that dependency explicitly (by adding it as a dependency in `package.json`), _even though_ it may also be a dependency of another module you install.

Comment: @mscdex Version was 1.*, installing newer version now, reporting back in a minute

Comment: @mscdex that was it really, thanks for you input, this thread can now be closed. Now `gulp` works perfectly!